# update query from a subquery

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I wanted to see if someone can help me with an update query.

I need to grab a `latitude` & `longitude` from a the same user that is in two `accounts`. therefore i am trying to `update` lat/long in a users table for one account based off of the same user in another account. I am matching the users up by phone number and last name. I tried a `subquery` but am having difficulty.

I was thinking of something like the following:

```
update users
set lat = getlat, long = getlong
inner join (select lat as getlat, long as get long from users where account_id = '1')
on phone = phone and last name = lastname
where account_id = '2' and lat IS NULL and long IS NULL
```

Am I going in the right direction???

Thanks in advance for any assistance!!!!

Comment: are you testing us? `i wanted to see` or you mean you need help?

Answer (score 0):

You need `Alias` name to your `sub-query`

Also select the `phone` and `lastname` column in the `sub-query` to join it back to the `Users` table

```
update U
set U.lat = A.getlat, U.long = A.getlong
From users U
inner join 
(
select lat as getlat, long as getlong,phone ,lastname
from users 
where account_id = '1'
) A
on U.phone = A.phone and U.lastname = A.lastname
where account_id = '2' 
and lat IS NULL 
and long IS NULL
```

Comment: You guys are a piece of work!!!! That worked beautifully!!!! Thank you very much!